# Angular 9 - BehaviorSubject serves previous value

Tags: rxjs, angular9

I am trying to come with a solution for a generic way of getting and assigning data to a component. I am playing with a BehaviorSubject as I think it is a the right candidate for that job. Here is some code:

service:

```
public listSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]>;

constructor(private service: someservice) {
   this.listSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
}

public requestList(id: number) {
this.someservice.get('url')
.subscribe(data => {
  this.listSubject.next([data]);
});
```

}

```
public get list(): any[] {
  if (this.listSubject.value.length > 0) {
    return [this.projectListSubject.value];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Implementation:

```
constructor(public service: AwaAlertsService) {
  // need full list first
  this.service.requestProjectList(1);
  this.list = this.service.projectList;
}

this.service.requestList(id);
this.list = this.service.list;
```

It works except that I am getting previous values.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in this example `BehaviorSubject` is redundant, because you can simply assign the list to a property like `: Array<any>` and it will do the same without overhead of `rxjs`.

But if you turn the list to be an observable, then `BehaviorSubject` makes sense, because now it notifies when the list has been changed and you can share it among your application.

```js
constructor(private service: someservice) {
   this.listSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[] | null>(null);
}

public get list$(): Observable<any[] | null> {
  return this.projectListSubject;
}
```

and later in a component code or template

```js
this.doSomething = service.list$.pipe(
  // ....
);
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="service.list$ | async as items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="items">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items"> {{ item }} </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I am getting Type 'Observable<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push at the line:  this.doSomething = service.list$.pipe(

Comment: depends on how you defined typed of `doSomething`, in case of pipe it's `Observable<any[] | null>`. But the idea of a pipe is to transform data in the stream, because it's not clear what you use instead of `...` - it's hard to guess the right type. You can put there `Observable<any>` as a temp solution.

Comment: I was able to get through type errors using what you are saying. But when I run these two lines for the first time: this.service.requestList(id);
        this.list = this.service.list; I get null, for the second time it returns the previous value and so forth.

Comment: That's what I mean with my answer - in current implementation there's no reason to use `BeahaviorSubject` because its value is used as a static data, not async pipe. To benefit from its usage you need to connect its stream somewhere - to a `pipe` or to a template via `async` pipe.

Comment: Well, my idea was when this method is requested: public requestList(id: number) {
this.someservice.get('url')
.subscribe(data => {
  this.listSubject.next([data]);
}); it populates the BeahaviorSubject  with latest value. Then anywhere in the implementation I get its value as: this.service.projectList. I am sure I missing something.

Comment: right, instead of `.next` you can do `this.projectList = data`, it will be the same effect. Because it's not reactive, to make it reactive you need to have streams of data, not only subscriptions. and when you have a stream of `projectList` then you can connect it anywhere and react on its updates.

Comment: try to implement a component that renders amount of items in the list. and the goal is - that `requestList` is executed every 5 seconds and every time it gets different amount of data back. I hope it can show you how the data flow should be organised and where `BehaviorSubject` shines. And for this task you should have none subscriptions in the component. only `service.requestList` and access to `projectList `.

Comment: So, it is rendering amount of items in the list that triggers stream generation in the first place?

Comment: yes, once you attach a stream somewhere - you can listen on it, and to do it via `async` pipe of angular templates is a quite good demo.

Comment: So, if I have a grid and where I need to show some data after a user selects new type of project list I dont really need BeahaviorSubject to constantly update the grid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213698/discussion-between-satantime-and-mark).

Comment: I am back. Are you available?